# Good syntax for anonymous function that is called conditionally

Tags: callback, closures, anonymous-function

I am probably looking for something that is impossible, but anyway let's give it a try. Please consider the following pseudo code that is performing some conditional, remote operation, that executes callback upon completion. But the code in the callback needs to be executed even if remote operation was not neccessary:

```
if (needsToSave)
{
  performRemoteOperation(operationParameters, function() {
    doSomeCleanup();
    doSomeMoreCleanup();
    setSomeStatus();
  });
}
else
{
    doSomeCleanup();
    doSomeMoreCleanup();
    setSomeStatus();
}
```

I find this code particularly ugly and unmanageable. It is easy to omit a change done to callback block in relevant unconditional block. There is an obvious solution of wrapping code in some named function, but it isn't anonymous inline code anymore then. :-)

The best I can think of is to wrap whole code in some conditional caller:

```
function conditionalCall(condition, action, callback)
{
  if (condition)
    action(callback)
  else
    callback()
}
```

Then my code would fold to:

```
conditionalCall(needsToSave,
  function(_callback) {
    performRemoteOperation(operationParameters, _callback)
  },
  function()
  {
    doSomeCleanup();
    doSomeMoreCleanup();
    setSomeStatus();
  }
);
```

...but I am not absolutely sure, whether this is more readable and manageable. Especially when lots of local/remote/callback parameters/closure variables get involved or one needs to "embed" one remote call within another call's callback. I hope there is some better syntax that could be used in such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In can be simpified:

```
var finallyFunction = function {
    doSomeCleanup();
    doSomeMoreCleanup();
    setSomeStatus();
}    

if (needsToSave)    
    performRemoteOperation(operationParameters, finallyFunction);
else
    finallyFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I stated that named functions are not an option here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a closure problem. Assuming "remote operation" to mean "asynchronous operation", then it's to do with handling asynchronous responses.

For sure, anonymous function(s) can be (and typically will be) employed in this kind of situation, but remember that "anonymous function" is *not* a synonym for "closure". Forgegt (almost) everything you learned in PHP, which is not a great learning ground for lexical closures.

If my assumption is correct, and we are indeed talking about asynchronicity, then jQuery's Deferreds/promises make for a rather neat solution.

```
// First make sure performRemoteOperation() returns a promise,
function performRemoteOperation(operationParameters) {
    ...
    return promise;//for example a jqXHR object, as generated by $.ajax() and its shorthand methods.
}

function myFunction(needsToSave) {
    var p = needsToSave ? performRemoteOperation(operationParameters) : $.Deferred.resolve().promise();
    //At this point `p` is either an unresolved promise returned by performRemoteOperation(), or a resolved promise generated in the line above.
    p.done(function() {
        //This function fires when the remote operation successfully completes, or immediately if `needsToSave` was false.
        doSomeCleanup();
        doSomeMoreCleanup();
        setSomeStatus();
    });
    return p;//A promise is returned for good measure, in case further chaining is necessary where myFunction() is called.
}

//Sample calls
myFunction(false);

myFunction(true).then(function() {
        alert("successfully saved");
    }, function() {
        alert("error: something went wrong");
    });
```

Of course, you could refactor the code into a single function if you wished but it's arguably easier to understand as two functions, as indicated in the question.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. I meant anonymous functions - I updated the title just now. As for PHP I didn't even know it had such constructs... :-) Thanks for a nice solution though.